Dual Boot Linux/OSX with Shared Partition
How do I create a shared partition on a dual-boot OSX/Linux such that both have read/write access to that partition?
It's a MacBook 2015 running OSX 12.7.3. [edit] I would use the most recent version of Ubuntu.[/edit] I want both OS's to have that access so that I can load all my files onto it (eg, ODTs, Scrivener, etc.).
I have found basic instructions for the dual boot and am confident I can follow them (here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-linux-macbook-pro/).
I have not found instructions on how to make the partition read/writable from both boots (this page is the closest I've gotten: How do I share storage while dual-booting Mac OS X and Ubuntu 12.04.1?).

As a side note, there are means to read ext4 from macOS as well as means to read HFS+ partitions / APFS volumes from Ubuntu, so an additional partition, albeit handy, is not mandatory.

Yes, I've read about this. My concern is that it seems to involve turning off "journaling," which I'd like to avoid because my life is on this MacBook. That's why a partition seemed like a safer bet. Am I wrong?

You've not provided any specific OS/release details (you do mention Ubuntu and an off-topic Ubuntu-based system but no product/release details) which are a starting point.  I'd keep $HOME separate for each OS (unless timing between OSes is very close; you gave no release details (except for osx) which is critical here!) and store files you want both to access in a common file-system.. which can be anything that both can use... (including as example NTFS that is foreign to both... but you just choose whatever fs that both handle well).

I'm very new at this, and I don't know what half of these terms mean. Is there a step-by-step guide to this kind if thing somewhere or is the solution I'm imagining not the best for a reason I'm I unaware or?

@orian then you make backups and backups of backups. no need for journaling guiverc has the right idea. Both OS completely each on a partition. and create a data partition for both using a filesystem both understand. you can do that last bit afterwards: say 50Gb for Ubuntu A good portion for MACOS, Keep the remainder unused and add it afterwards that way you can search online for both OS what the best course is
